# How do you edit the enchantment level for armor files? (not in-game)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found a mod that was a "Ring of Arcane Inspiration" on nexus, which basically grants you free magicka for all schools of magic.

I would like to know if it is possible to do something similar, and raise the enchantment on the nightingale hood to a higher % - which file do I edit, and what program to use?

Comment: In a few weeks, you'll be able to use the creation engine that Bethesda is finalizing. Is it urgent?

Comment: I hope "Is it urgent?" was not sarcasm, because no, nothing about a RPG is urgent :) I just don't follow the official blogs that well, so I did not know of the date of the creation engine. I apologize if my question seemed to radiate a sense of emergency, I certainly did not intend it to.

Comment: Not sarcasm. Teasing perhaps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found mod that provides a set of craftable/enchantable/improvable Nightingale Armor. http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=5247